# Increment The Last String Index Value

Tags: java

I have `String` like this

```
String ipAddress= "192.168.1.12";
```

I want to auto increment the last index value 12 to

```
13
14
15
```

so it will be like this

```
192.168.1.13
192.168.1.14
192.168.1.15
```

Comment: You need to [show](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) some code. Also, check [parseInt](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm)

Comment: Voted to close this question as "too broad" unless the code-work isn't being shown.

Comment: Check also string.split

Comment: good question, and im glad you got answers. it may be wise however to include what code you have tried next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd break the string up by the `.` character, convert the last element to an int, increment it, and rejoin them:

```
String ipAddress= "192.168.1.12";

String[] elements = ipAddress.split("\\.");
elements[elements.length - 1] = 
    String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(elements[elements.length - 1]) + 1);

String newAddress = String.join(".", elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to split the initial string at the last dot, get the numeric value of the last part, increment it and append it to the initial part of the string:

```
    int posOfLastNumber = ipAddress.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
    String last = ipAddress.substring(posOfLastNumber);
    String first = ipAddress.substring(0, posOfLastNumber);

    int lastNumber = Integer.parseInt(last) + 1;
    ipAddress = first + lastNumber;
```

Comment: Your solution is becoming similar to mine... :)

Comment: @user3437460 so it seems. Great minds think alike :-)

Comment: Yes, I have to agree with that statement.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use split as well. But it was already shown. Alternatively, you can simply use `substring` and `lastIndexOf` to get position of last dot.

```
int idx = ipAddress.lastIndexOf(".")+1;
int last = Math.min(Integer.parseInt((ipAddress.substring(idx)))+1, 255);
String newIpAddress = ipAddress.substring(0, idx) + last;
```

The above can be written in one line if you want.

Comment: **Remarks:** I also did a check to ensure ip address does not exceed 255.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a quote:

> "Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around."
>    - Eric Raymond, The Cathedral and the Bazaar

What you have is more than a simple string.  What you have is an object which has a string representation and some additional functionality.  Which could be something as simple as this:

```
class IPAddress {
    private int firstByte;
    private int secondByte;
    private int thirdByte;
    private int fourthByte;

    public IPAddress(int firstByte, int secondByte, int thirdByte, int fourthByte) {
        this.firstByte = firstByte;
        // etc.
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%1$s.%2$s.%3$s.%4$s", firstByte, secondByte, thirdByte, fourthByte);
    }

    public void increment() {
        // this would be a good place for bounds checking
        fourthByte++;
    }
}
```

This encapsulates the functionality into the `IPAddress` data type itself, rather than requiring that consuming code performs all sorts of string parsing logic on it.  All any consuming code ever needs to do is call `.increment()` on the object.

If the original input is a string, then you can simply create another constructor here which accepts a string and parses it into the four bytes of the address.

Answer (score 0):

First, `String` is immutable. If I understand your question, you want something that begin at one ip address and return what would be the next. By incrementing overflowing octets (of the ip adress). Something like,

```
private static String incrementIp(String str) {
    String[] parts = str.split("\\.");
    int oct1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int oct2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    int oct3 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
    int oct4 = Integer.parseInt(parts[3]);
    oct4++;
    if (oct4 > 255) {
        oct4 = 0;
        oct3++;
    }
    if (oct3 > 255) {
        oct3 = 0;
        oct2++;
    }
    if (oct2 > 255) {
        oct2 = 0;
        oct1++;
    }
    if (oct1 > 255) {
        oct1 = 0;
    }
    return String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", oct1, oct2, oct3, oct4);
}
```

We might test this by incrementing 10 times like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ipAddress = "192.168.1.254";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Before: %s, After: %s%n", ipAddress,
                incrementIp(ipAddress));
        ipAddress = incrementIp(ipAddress);
    }
}
```

Which outputs (the presumably *expected*)

```
Before: 192.168.1.254, After: 192.168.1.255
Before: 192.168.1.255, After: 192.168.2.0
Before: 192.168.2.0, After: 192.168.2.1
Before: 192.168.2.1, After: 192.168.2.2
Before: 192.168.2.2, After: 192.168.2.3
Before: 192.168.2.3, After: 192.168.2.4
Before: 192.168.2.4, After: 192.168.2.5
Before: 192.168.2.5, After: 192.168.2.6
Before: 192.168.2.6, After: 192.168.2.7
Before: 192.168.2.7, After: 192.168.2.8
```